# How to attach publication into the existing publication target?

Tags: publishing, core-service

I want to publish my pages from the publication so I want to attach this publication into existing publication target. Here is my current code:

```
PublicationTargetData pd=(PublicationTargetData)client.read("tcm:0-7-65537",new ReadOptions());     
ArrayOfLinkToPublicationData linkpub=new ArrayOfLinkToPublicationData();        
LinkToPublicationData plinkData=new LinkToPublicationData();        
plinkData.setIdRef("tcm:0-234-1");      
List l=linkpub.getLinkToPublicationData();  
l.add(plinkData);   
pd.setPublications(linkpub);    
client.update(pd,new ReadOptions());
```

This code is successfully attaching the Publication into the Publication Target but it unfortunately it replaces the Publication Target with the new one. But I don't want to remove the previous Publication from the Publication Target. So kindly suggest any solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are instantiating a new `ArrayOfLinkToPublicationData();`, but instead you should take one which is already available on your publication target `pd`, add desired element and assign it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method to achieve the desired result

```
List<string> validPublications = new List<string>();
            ///Gets the list of Publications exisitng for current Publishing Target
            PublicationTargetData target = (PublicationTargetData)client.Read(PublishingTargetUri, new ReadOptions());
            foreach (LinkToPublicationData pub in target.Publications)
            {
                validPublications.Add(pub.IdRef);
            }
```

But this is not working in Web 8.5 when you pass a TargetType instead of PublicationTargetType(this returns null always in Web 8.5). Anyone has a solution for this scenario?